# IOS 8 : CLVisit in CoreLocation

Tags: ios8, core-location

I m trying to use new CLVisit feature in my app to monitor user's visit, i followed the WWDC-14 video and implemented every thing, but *locationManager:didVisit* is not calling at all. I set the NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription key, enable the "Location updates" background mode in Capabilities, and include the following in ViewDidLoad of my class :

```
_locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
_locationManager.delegate = self;
[_locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
[_locationManager startMonitoringVisits];
```

There is no documentation available on min TIME required to stay at specific place for a visit or anything about DISTANCE between places.
I tried to test it using GPX file and in the building by staying at different places for more than 10 min, but *locationManager:didVisit* delegate didn't fired.

Please help me, how to test CLVisits, or if i missed anything in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I´ve been testing CLVisits with this code and works perfect to monitor my day a day
https://github.com/steveschauer/TestCLVisit